# How can I flip loaded image sprites? Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, transform, sprite

I want to flip these sprites so that they're facing left. That way I can use the sprite images for my player running left when I press K_LEFT. Currently have it where if you press the right arrow your player moves right and animates.

```
            self.sprites = []
            self.sprites.append(py.image.load('I1.png'))
            self.sprites.append(py.image.load('R0.png'))
            self.sprites.append(py.image.load('R1.png'))
            self.sprites.append(py.image.load('R2.png'))
            self.sprites.append(py.image.load('R3.png'))
            self.sprites.append(py.image.load('R4.png'))
            self.sprites.append(py.image.load('R5.png'))
            self.current_sprite = 0
            self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (x, y)
            self.hit_rect = PLAYER_RECT_HIT
            self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
            self.pos = vec(x, y)
            self.vel = vec(0, 0)
            self.acc = vec(0, 0)
            self.is_animating = False

def get_keys(self):
    self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAVITY)
    keys = py.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[py.K_RIGHT]:
        self.acc.x += PLAYER_ACC
        self.animate()
    if keys[py.K_LEFT]:
        self.acc.x -= PLAYER_ACC

def animate(self):
    self.is_animating = True

def update(self):
    self.get_keys()

    if self.is_animating:
        self.current_sprite += 0.2
        if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
            self.current_sprite = 0
            self.is_animating = False
    self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]

    self.pos += self.vel
    self.hit_rect.centerx = self.pos.x
    wall_collision(self, self.game.walls, 'x')
    self.hit_rect.centery = self.pos.y
    wall_collision(self, self.game.walls, 'y')
    self.rect.center = self.hit_rect.center

    # Apply Friction
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
    # Equation of motion
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try
pygame.transform.flip()

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.flip

When you blit to screen you could check if 'left key' was pressed and transform.flip

'flip(Surface, xbool, ybool) -> Surface'

eg.

```
if key == 'left':
    self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image, False, True), self.rect)
```

example code:

```
import pygame
import pygame.sprite
import sys


class WalkingSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ A class to manage an animated sprite. """

    def __init__(self):
        super(WalkingSprite, self).__init__()
        self.direction = True

        self.images = []
        for number in range(1, 11):
            self.images.append(pygame.image.load(f'images/walking_sprite{number}.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = 300, 200

    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0

        if self.direction:
            self.image = self.images[self.index]
        else:
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.index], True, False)


BG_COLOR = pygame.Color('white')
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
walking_sprite = WalkingSprite()
sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group(walking_sprite)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                walking_sprite.direction = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                walking_sprite.direction = True

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    sprite_group.update()
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    sprite_group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform.rotate is what your looking for.

```
 for sprite in self.sprites :
     pygame.transform.rotate (sprite, angle)
```

Comment: The OP asked for mirroring the images to make a right looking image face left. The transform method `rotate()` will not help with that. The transform method `flip()` answer by @james is the correct answer.